# Select2: how to set "title" property of a multiple select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I noticed that there's a mousehover title that is set on the

elements when using select: multiple. However, I seem to have no control over it. What I want to do is to set the tag name to the product name, and the hover title to the product code. I tried the following:

```
$('#repair_parts').select2({
  multiple: true,
  ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/part/show",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        data: params.term
      }
      return query;
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      results = [];
      for (i = 0; i<data.length; ++i) {
        results[i] = {title: data[i].code, id: data[i].id, text:data[i].code+": "+data[i].name};
      }
      return {results: results};
    },
  },
  templateSelection: function (data, container) {
    container.prop('title', data.title);
    return text;
  }
});
```

But to no avail. The title is still the same.

Comment: what is the variable `text` in `return text`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I did was just fine, however, the PHP script that loaded the options from the database would not have the correct title tags. I used JavaScript to change the formatting of the tag and done.